# How to see mathematical expressions correctly in a Help html of a function (appearing after right-click) in R GUI?

Tags: r, user-interface, revolution-r, helpfile

I am using 32-bit Revolution R Enterprise (7.3) GUI for R (3.1.1) on 64-bit Windows 8.1.

When a function (say, urca::ca.jo) is right-clicked in Object Browser of RevoREnt after its package is loaded, an html file is shown in an opened window: in my notebook, it is http://127.0.0.1:25449/library/urca/html/ca.jo.html whose title is "R: Johansen Procedure for VAR - Revolution R Enterprise Help - Microsoft Document Explorer".

In this window, unfortunately, mathematical expressions are displayed in a latex-type code such as:

Details
Given a general VAR of the form:
\bold{X}_t = \bold{Π}*1 \bold{X}*{t-1} + … + \bold{Π}*k \bold{X}*{t-k} + \bold{μ} + \bold{Φ D}_t + \bold{\varepsilon}_t , \quad (t = 1, …, T),

Naturally, understanding what is going on from these expressions are really cumbersome. I am going to the PDF file of the related package to see clearly what these expressions are. Is not there any way to see them in the right-clicked-opened-window without going to PDF file?

By the way, I do not know whether this behaviour is same in "Base R" and "RStudio" GUIs.

I think there are many coder in my position, surely, we would greatly appreciate any help to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://127.0.0.1 is a location on your computer, not accessible to anyone else. All users have a similar mechanism for viewing their help files. The authors of that package do not appear to understand how to write expressions in the particular markdown/markup language that the R help browser uses. That's what we are all seeing. You should probably look at the PDF version of that function's documentation: 
Page 11 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/urca.pdf

If you look at the "Writing R Extensions" document you will find the secret incantation in section 2.6 which on my machine is at: http://127.0.0.1:29569/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Mathematics (but it appears that the port is different on your machine.) To find it I simply searched on the word "Greek" in that document:

> To this end, the two commands `\eqn{`*latex*}{*ascii*} and `\deqn{`*latex*}{*ascii*} are used. Whereas `\eqn` is used for “inline” formulae (corresponding to TeX’s $…$), `\deqn` gives “displayed equations” (as in LaTeX’s `displaymath` environment, or TeX’s $$…$$). Both arguments are treated as ‘verbatim’ text.

Comment: I looked at the PDF file of urca. You say "..how to write expressions in the particular markdown/markup language that the R help browser uses..". Do you know any R package from which we can clearly see math'l expressions in html file in R help browser?

Comment: Thanks 42-, your reply is quite helpful. Your way clearly simplifies the things to great extent. That said, look at stats:FDist's help inter alia (Fdist.html) to see f(x) = Γ((n1 + n2)/2) / (Γ(n1/2) Γ(n2/2)) (n1/n2)^(n1/2) x^(n1/2 - 1) (1 + (n1/n2) x)^-(n1 + n2)/2. This is understandable since no backslash latex code is seen. By the way, we need to wait more, I think, to see long fraction line for 2 below (n1 + n2) where 1 and 2 are subscripted, properly-shown integral signs, reflection of all other math'l notation etc. as they appear in PDFs.